# MongoDB/Mongoid sorting acts weird

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, sorting

I have following object:

```
class Node
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Tree

   field :path, type: Array
end
```

The `path` array is used to store the global position in the tree, so a root node would have its position stored: `{ path: [0] }` and a children would have its position and the root position like so stored: `{ path: [0, 0] }`

When I query for them with `Node.asc(:path)` and then ask for the paths, I get something like this:

```
[[3, 0, 0],
 [7, 0],         # WTF?
 [3, 0],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [2, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0],
 …
]
```

However when I do the ordering in Ruby I get the correct result:

```
[[0],
 [2],
 [2, 0],
 [2, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 1],
 [2, 0, 1, 0],
 [3],
 …
]
```

What is going on with MongoDB, is this related with indexing?